# Adding only one record in adf

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I would like to ask if you know any property in adf or any idea in order to allow only one adding in a table when i go to insert a record.I am using Jdeveloper 12c

Comment: Very ambiguous question. Provide some information: Do you have a problem with your view objects or you have problem with your entities? What are you trying to do, and what is the expected result, and what is the real result you are getting? What are you using to insert that record? ViewObject or Entity? Do you have a form or just testing your Model project?

Comment: my problem is with the view objects,i am trying to insert a record in a table and then i would like a pop up or any validation to display in my browser that i cannot insert a second record.I am trying to insert an attribute which has date datatype,i thing it is simple..Looking for ideas like to create an expression in action listener or write some code in view object row ..whatever...

Comment: Am I getting this right? You are trying to restrict the user from adding more than one record in a table? Are doing it using a form?

Comment: yes,exactly..i am doing it using a form which i go via a create insert method from the view object i want

Answer (score 0):

Restricting user from creating more than one record (may be one record per day or ...) can be done using a very wide range of choices:

1. Create database level trigger and throw an exception. Then you can catch it in your java code, and showing your Popup message to the user by throwing a `JboException` to the ViewController layer. There you can show a popup message using `ADFUtils` or `JSFUtils` classes. If you are using JHeadStart along with ADF, it will show an error message popup for every `JboException` which has been thrown.
2. You can write some code in the `doDml()` method of your entity to make such a restriction. Then you can throw some exception as explained in #1.
3. You can create a **Method Validation** in your entity, and make it entity level. Then write the logic of your restriction in that method of your entity, and return false as a failure. This false return will notify the form which user work with properly.

As you didn't provide any code you've tried before I've just tried to brain storm a little to help you. I think you can use one of the above ways to achieve what you want.

Good Luck.